# Precargar imágenes con JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, web

estoy intentando precargar imágenes del Background con Js, la cuestión es que lo estoy asignando desde el archivo `css`, es decir, estoy usando `.css('background : background[0])` de jquery y no una imagen `<img>` como  tal dentro de mi documento HTML . 
Quería ver si hay una manera de precargar las imágenes para evitar el parpadeo blanco que genera el salto entre cada imagen.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Biópolis</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="main.css" /> -->
    <!-- <script src="menu.js"></script> -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">


</head>
<body>

   <div class="cuerpo">

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row mb-5 logo">
            <div class="col-sm-3 logo-col">
                <img src="./img/Logo biópolis ok calado.png">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light fixed-bottom d-md-block d-lg-none">
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="">MENU</span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="./index.html">inicio <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="./biopolis/index.html">biópolis</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="./arquitectura/index.html">arquitectura</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="./planeacion/index.html">planeación</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="./equipo/index.html">equipo</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="./contacto/index.html">contacto</a>
                </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>

    <div class="container contenedor">
        <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center caption">
            <div class="col-sm-10 text-center">
                <label class="title">Una comunidad interdisciplinaria</label><br><label class="subtitle">construímos alternativas para desarrollos residenciales, urbanos turísticos, responables con la naturaleza, la cultura y el ser humano</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container menu d-lg-block d-none">
        <div class="row d-flex justify-content-right">
            <div class="col-sm-12 text-right">
                <ul>
                    <li> <a href="./index.html" class="seleccionado">inicio</a> </li>
                    <li> <a href="./biopolis/index.html">biópolis</a> </li>
                    <li> <a href="./arquitectura/index.html">arquitectura</a> </li>
                    <li> <a href="./planeacion/index.html">planeación</a> </li>
                    <li> <a href="./equipo/index.html">equipo</a> </li>
                    <li> <a href="./contacto/index.html">contacto</a> </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>



    </div>
</div>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<!-- <script src="./js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="./js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 -->
 <script src="https://unpkg.com/imagesloaded@4/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js"></script>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
        var header = $('.cuerpo');
        let title = $('.title');
        let sub = $('.subtitle');

        let phrasesTitle = new Array(
            'Una comunidad interdisciplinaria',
            'Diseñamos un plan integral',
            'Identificamos la vocación del sitio'
        )

        let phrasesSub = new Array(
            'construímos alternativas para desarrollos residenciales, urbanos turísticos, responables con la naturaleza, la cultura y el ser humano',
            'en conjunto con nuestros clientes, cada proyecto es una solución que contribuye al desarrollo positivo de su entorno',
            'a través del plan maestro hacen la interpretación de los valores ambientales y escénicos que definen criterios y lineamientos de diseño'
        )

        var backgrounds = new Array(
            'url(./img/00_Home/01.jpg)'
        , 'url(./img/00_Home/02.jpg)'
        , 'url(./img/00_Home/03.jpg)'
        , 'url(./img/00_Home/04.jpg)'
        , 'url(./img/00_Home/05.jpg)'
        , 'url(./img/00_Home/06.jpg)'
        );



        var current = 0, actual = 0;

        function nextBackground() {
            current++;
            current = current % backgrounds.length;
            header.css('background-image', backgrounds[current]);
        }


        function nextCaption (){
            actual++;
            actual = actual % phrasesSub.length;
            title.text(phrasesTitle[actual]);
            sub.text(phrasesSub[actual]);
        }
        setInterval(nextCaption, 10000);
        setInterval(nextBackground, 5000);


        title.text(phrasesTitle[0]);
        sub.text(phrasesSub[0]);
        header.css('background-image', backgrounds[0]) ;
    });

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

La clase que pertenece al cambio del background es `pagina` 
Espero alguno pueda ayudarme, gracias

Answer (score 1):

con el evento window load:
que espera que todo el documento este cargado para ejecutarse!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Biópolis</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="main.css" /> -->
    <!-- <script src="menu.js"></script> -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">


</head>
<body>

   <div class="cuerpo">

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row mb-5 logo">
            <div class="col-sm-3 logo-col">
                <img src="./img/Logo biópolis ok calado.png">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light fixed-bottom d-md-block d-lg-none">
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="">MENU</span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="./index.html">inicio <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="./biopolis/index.html">biópolis</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="./arquitectura/index.html">arquitectura</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="./planeacion/index.html">planeación</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="./equipo/index.html">equipo</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="./contacto/index.html">contacto</a>
                </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>

    <div class="container contenedor">
        <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center caption">
            <div class="col-sm-10 text-center">
                <label class="title">Una comunidad interdisciplinaria</label><br><label class="subtitle">construímos alternativas para desarrollos residenciales, urbanos turísticos, responables con la naturaleza, la cultura y el ser humano</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container menu d-lg-block d-none">
        <div class="row d-flex justify-content-right">
            <div class="col-sm-12 text-right">
                <ul>
                    <li> <a href="./index.html" class="seleccionado">inicio</a> </li>
                    <li> <a href="./biopolis/index.html">biópolis</a> </li>
                    <li> <a href="./arquitectura/index.html">arquitectura</a> </li>
                    <li> <a href="./planeacion/index.html">planeación</a> </li>
                    <li> <a href="./equipo/index.html">equipo</a> </li>
                    <li> <a href="./contacto/index.html">contacto</a> </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>



    </div>
</div>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<!-- <script src="./js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="./js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 -->
 <script src="https://unpkg.com/imagesloaded@4/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js"></script>

<script>

    $(window).load(function(){
        var header = $('.cuerpo');
        let title = $('.title');
        let sub = $('.subtitle');

        let phrasesTitle = new Array(
            'Una comunidad interdisciplinaria',
            'Diseñamos un plan integral',
            'Identificamos la vocación del sitio'
        )

        let phrasesSub = new Array(
            'construímos alternativas para desarrollos residenciales, urbanos turísticos, responables con la naturaleza, la cultura y el ser humano',
            'en conjunto con nuestros clientes, cada proyecto es una solución que contribuye al desarrollo positivo de su entorno',
            'a través del plan maestro hacen la interpretación de los valores ambientales y escénicos que definen criterios y lineamientos de diseño'
        )

        var backgrounds = new Array(
            'url(./img/00_Home/01.jpg)'
        , 'url(./img/00_Home/02.jpg)'
        , 'url(./img/00_Home/03.jpg)'
        , 'url(./img/00_Home/04.jpg)'
        , 'url(./img/00_Home/05.jpg)'
        , 'url(./img/00_Home/06.jpg)'
        );



        var current = 0, actual = 0;

        function nextBackground() {
            current++;
            current = current % backgrounds.length;
            header.css('background-image', backgrounds[current]);
        }


        function nextCaption (){
            actual++;
            actual = actual % phrasesSub.length;
            title.text(phrasesTitle[actual]);
            sub.text(phrasesSub[actual]);
        }
        setInterval(nextCaption, 10000);
        setInterval(nextBackground, 5000);


        title.text(phrasesTitle[0]);
        sub.text(phrasesSub[0]);
        header.css('background-image', backgrounds[0]) ;
    });

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

referencia:
[windows load](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload)